# Classic ASP Function equivalent to PHP's

Tags: php, asp-classic

Using PHP and ASP on a project. A form in PHP captures the day, month and year of a birth date. Then it's inserted into a database as the variable currentSeconds. I can get the years from variable `$currentSeconds` in PHP no problem using the 2nd code snippet

1st Code Snippet

```
$day=$_POST[day];
if ($day<10){
$day="0".$day;
}

$currentSeconds = strtotime($day." ".$_POST[month]." ".$_POST[year]);
```

2nd Code Snippet

```
$nYears = date('Y',time()-$currentSeconds)-1970;
```

How can I get the number of years using `$currentSeconds` variable, but under classic ASP? For this example `$currentSeconds = 136612800`, which should give the number of years as 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
Const seconds = 136612800
dim birthday: birthday = DateAdd("s", seconds, "01/01/1970 00:00:00")
dim age: age = DateDiff("yyyy", birthday, Now)
Response.Write age
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are doing there but if you want to calculate the difference between 2 dates you could use the `DateDiff` function in classic asp.

```
nYears = DateDiff("yyyy", birthdate, now)
```